# SetLayoutParams not works in getView..last element only updated

Tags: android, android-layout

I set my view(button) height at runtime in baseAdapter getView().

But My layoutParams set only for last element of getview.

**My getView code:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_round_table, null);
        btnRoundTables = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_table);

     //set the btn height at runtime
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = btnRoundTables.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                btnRoundTables.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                int btnWidth=btnRoundTables.getMeasuredWidth();
                btnRoundTables.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnWidth, btnWidth));
                return true;
            }
        });
       HashMap<String, String> mainMap = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        btnRoundTables.setText(mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TITLE));
        btnRoundTables.setTag(mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TABLE_ID));
        btnRoundTables.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("table name" + mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TITLE), "listadapterGrid");

    }
        return vi;
}
```

**My output:**

[image]

Thanks for help..

Comment: Please provide your full `getView` code. Your code seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong in getView. You must use the ViewHolder pattern in your adapters.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_round_table, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.btnRoundTables = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_table);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }else{
       holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

     //set the btn height at runtime
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = holder.btnRoundTables.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                holder.btnRoundTables.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                int btnWidth=holder.btnRoundTables.getMeasuredWidth();
                holder.btnRoundTables.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnWidth, btnWidth));
                return true;
            }
        });
       HashMap<String, String> mainMap = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        holder.btnRoundTables.setText(mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TITLE));
        holder.btnRoundTables.setTag(mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TABLE_ID));
        holder.btnRoundTables.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("table name" + mainMap.get(Keys.KEY_TITLE), "listadapterGrid");

    }
        return vi;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    Button btnRoundTables;
}
```

Comment: The main purpose is better memory management and reducing CPU usage. Refer to this article please. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html